# Circumventing closure of questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, deleted-questions

After some time with the "3 votes to close" working it seems that, overall, this improved the signal to noise ratio.

- Non-salvageable questions, do-my-homework requests and "let me google that for you" are closed very quickly, even before some quick answers are posted
- I've noticed some premature closures happening even without comments, but some were improved and reopened

It begins to concern me if the closures will continue to avoid the noise: I've seen several examples of deleted questions being closed, deleted and opened again (sometimes minutes or hours later, sometimes it takes 1 day or more).

Auto-detecting that the new question is mostly a copy-paste of the previous one may be harder to implement, but, would it be possible to make the deleted questions visible for everyone? Wouldn't it be a way of detecting the attempt to hide the closure? Even if a new account is created, the question would appear in the searches too.

Worth noting: sometimes the "new" question is actually improved based on the comments and the "delete and ask again" seems just a way to expedite the reopen process (with the problem that the feedback is lost).

Comment: If they keep doing this, the automatic question ban will eventually kick in, placing the user in a nasty place to be, where they can only ask one question after 6 months, then get banned again if it was poorly received. This automatic ban does take deleted posts in account.

Answer (score 2):

> Auto-detecting that the new question is mostly a copy-paste of the
> previous one may be harder to implement, but, would it be possible to
> make the deleted questions visible for everyone?

This would be a change that would have to happen network wide, and would be difficult for SE to change the privilege to view and vote on deleted questions is given at 10K rep - it takes time to learn how moderation works and to prove experience. This number is set by SE.

Questions rarely get deleted. Mods usually don't delete questions unless they have a very low question score or spam. Users are free to delete thier own questions whenever they would like which happens more often. There are also a few questions that get deleted by user votes, many of those have very low question scores also.

If you see any suspected duplicates, flag them and a mod will look at it.

Closeure is also different from deletion this is how closure works:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. My concern was specifically about users deleting their own questions to circumvent the reopen procedure described in the mentioned link. It seems it is just confirmation bias on my part and it doesn't happen that frequently. The flagging system (which I have used and worked for this specific case) is the way to go.

Comment: I think another part of it is that mods need to know about users that are doing this repeatedly, so that's why I see mainly has the flagging system used. If the user does this enough they'll probably need a suspension

Comment: Just a note that [the privilege to see deleted posts is on 10K](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), not 20K.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. Just *viewing* would be enough to facilitate the attempt to discourage this behavior I mentioned. Let's not worry about this any further.